# How to draw the tree in a "pitchfork" form?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, trees

How to set the options or other parameters in a TreePlot to draw the branching outside of the vertex? I.e. in a form similar to a dendrogram (but the dendrogram plot itself does not support the vertices).

Some as an example in the figure

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ClearAll[zigzag]
zigzag[][{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, ___] := Line @ 
   {{a, b}, {(a + c)/2, b}, {(a + c)/2, d}, {c, d}}
zigzag["Vertical"][{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, rest___] := Map[Reverse, 
  zigzag[][{{b, a}, {d, c}}, rest], {2}]
```

***Examples:***

```
vlabels = "v" <> ToString @ # & /@ Range[5]
edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5};

Graph[Range[5], edges,  
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[vlabels[[v]], Center]}, 
  VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> 16,
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", 
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> zigzag[], 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image]

With `"Orientation" -> Right` we get

[image]

For `Top` and `Bottom` orientations use `zigzag["Vertical"]`:

```
Graph[Range[5], edges,  
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[vlabels[[v]], Center]}, 
 VertexStyle -> White, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 16,
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", 
 VertexSize -> Large, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> zigzag["Vertical"], 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}]
```

[image]

Using `"Orientation" -> Top` gives

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]

TreeGraph[RandomInteger[{1, #}] \[UndirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[20], 
 ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexStyle -> White, VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", 
 VertexSize -> Large, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Gray],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> zigzag["Vertical"]]
```

[image]